# Classes and calling the properties Dynamically, Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have two swift classes with two fairly similar properties (I have made the ones below the same for the purpose of this question) I want to use. I want to call the properties dynamically in the ViewDidLoad and I have used an array as shown below so I can change the index and choose which class to call. Unfortunately I get the error

> Anyobject does not have a member named speciesType

What could I have missed or am I approaching the whole problem in the wrong way?

```
class Lion {
    var age = 45
    var speciesType = "Felidae"
}

class Lioness {
    var age = 10
    var speciesType = "Panthera"
}

var animal1 = Lion()
var animal2 = Lioness()

var animalKingDom = [animal1, animal2]

var colourChanging = animalKingDom[0].speciesType
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why dont you create a protocol that extracts out the common properties from both the classes.

```
class Lion {

    var age = 45
    var speciesType = "Felidae"
}

class Lioness {

    var age = 10
    var speciesType = "Panthera"
}

protocol LionType {
    var speciesType: String { get set }
    var age: Int { get set }
}

extension Lion: LionType { }
extension Lioness: LionType { }

var animal1 = Lion()
var animal2 = Lioness()

var animalKingDom: [LionType] = [animal1, animal2]

var colourChanging = animalKingDom[0].speciesType
```

I created a protocol LionType and added extension to both the classes to conform to the protocol. Since both the classes already have age and speciesType,  the classes will remain unchanged. And finally, a small modification to your animalKingDom array could make it work easily.

By the way, I added a protocol LionType, I think it makes more sense to name it AnimalType which fits for all animals not just lions :)

Comment: This is way, way too much for such a simple problem. I hope that OP never implements something like this for such a trivial case.

Comment: Well, why do you think it is too much ? Careful and thoughtful design are better than small code. The idea here is not to  give you  exact solution for problem but to show how you would tackle design difficulty.

Comment: @GeneratorOfOne Sweet! Perfect answer. Thanks. Will definitely use "Animal Type" for the example next time to avoid raised eyebrows about Male and Female in separate classes. ;) :)

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the syntax where you declare the protocol before the classes, and let the classes explicit implement the protocol upon creation.

```
import Cocoa

protocol Animal {
    var age: Int { get set }
    var speciesType: String { get set }
}

class Lion: Animal {
    var age: Int
    var speciesType: String

    init(age: Int, speciesType: String) {
        self.age = age
        self.speciesType = speciesType
    }
}

class Lioness: Animal {
    var age: Int
    var speciesType: String

    init(age: Int, speciesType: String) {
        self.age = age
        self.speciesType = speciesType
    }
}

var l1 = Lion(age: 5, speciesType: "Cat")
var l2 = Lioness(age: 6, speciesType: "Doge")

var animalArray: [Animal] = [l1, l2]

for animal in animalArray {
    print(animal.age)
    print(animal.speciesType)
}
```

Also I'm not sure I would give a class for both male and female of an animal. But it totally depends on your business domain.

Comment: Sweet! Thanks. And the male and female of an animal were just for the question. ;) :)

Answer (score 0):

The compiler infer that the generic type of your array is 'AnyObject'.
Try removing one element from your array, and the compiler will find the good type of your array.
The compiler is not able to know that Lion and Lioness has a property in common.

You can either make a superclass or a protocol like GeneratorOne suggests.

Answer (score -1):

I think that what you *really* want to do is have two *instances* of a single class (or better yet, if your real example is anything like this one, a `struct`). Let's keep using your `Lion` class. Two instances would then be

```
var lion = Lion()
lion.age = 45
lion.family = "Felidae"

var lioness = Lion()
lioness.age = 10
lioness.family = "Panthera"
```

(I'm ignoring the fact that your male and female are in different families. :))